# Busbar calculation

Tags: temperature, bus, derating

I am looking formula and factor involved in calculating DCDB and ACDB busbar calculation in string combiner box. Please share link or example calculating bus bar.

1. choosing proper bus bar
2. effect of temperature on bus bar
3. derating factor
4. heat loss using busbar

Answer (score 1):

It is no different than for wire. Most wiring standards will tell you the cross sectional area of the conductor needed to carry a certain current, and list all of the factors such as temperature and insulation derating.

Bus bars are just short wires with a single strand.

Comment: Shape I think plays a role in convection cooling, those increasing the current carrying capacity.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of searching, the best source I found was an old german DIN standard from 1975. https://www.sis.se/produkter/elektroteknik-24c2329a/elektriska-linor-och-kablar/linor/din43671/

However, rittal have incorporated the information from this in english and a more modern format in their catalogues. One which you can find below. https://www.rittal.com/imf/none/3_1978/